# how to manage username coming via two authentications

Tags: php, mysql, facebook-authentication

I am authenticating users for my website via different social networks.

They are provided with facilities like Sign in and Sign up via their social networks

Now problem is if user A has a facebook account with username "userme" and another user who used my website's own sign up system with username "userme", it makes a contradiction if

"User A sign up after user B" in log in my website.

During sign up user B would be alerted for not having "userme" as it already taken, but if user A "Log in" he would be never alerted as its a facebook authentication.

Please correct me if i am knowing something wrong or give a solution.

Comment: so make a composite username. `fb.foo` and `twt.foo`. same username, different sources.

Answer (score 0):

**Composite data method**

Given the way social logins work, it would probably be better if you stored your accounts using a hidden composite username (as Marc B suggested). Users who sign up manually would see their username as `myuser` - but a separate identifying (unique ID) field would store it as `myOwn_myuser` or `fb_myuser`.

**Complete Separation method**

Separate their Facebook username from Your Site's username. You might be giving them an ID prematurely when you could be better off asking them to confirm their facebook username as their *your-site* username after they log in for the first time. When a Facebook user logs into your site (initially), and their proposed username is already taken by an existing user, you could prompt them to create a new one, or generate a new one (`myuser2`).